# Finding percentage of rejection in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas data frame like given below

```
Id1     YEAR    CLAIM_STATUS   no_of_claims
 1  2019-01       4               1
 1  2019-01       5               1
 1  2019-02       4               1
 1  2019-02       5               1
 1  2019-03       4               6
 1  2019-03       5               2
 1  2019-04       5               1
 1  2019-04       6               1
 1  2019-05       5               2
 1  2019-06       4               1
 1  2019-06       5               1
```

Here claim_STATUS status 4 means claim is rejected I need to find percentage of claims rejected for each Id1 at each year where percentage of claims rejected is calculated like

```
claim-status-4/(claim-status-4+claim-status-5+claim-status-6)
```

in above table claim rejected percentage is `(1/(1+6+3))*100 = 10%`

I need to convert above dataframe into output given below:

```
Id1   YEAR_MO    % of claims rejected
1   2019-01         50%
1   2019-02         50%
1   2019-03         75%
1   2019-04         0%
1   2019-05         0%
1   2019-06         50%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test column `claim_STATUS` and assign back, aggregate `sum` and last divide columns:

```
print (df.assign(CLAIM_STATUS = df['CLAIM_STATUS'].eq(4).mul(df['no_of_claims'])))
    Id1     YEAR  CLAIM_STATUS  no_of_claims
0     1  2019-01             1             1
1     1  2019-01             0             1
2     1  2019-02             1             1
3     1  2019-02             0             1
4     1  2019-03             6             6
5     1  2019-03             0             2
6     1  2019-04             0             1
7     1  2019-04             0             1
8     1  2019-05             0             2
9     1  2019-06             1             1
10    1  2019-06             0             1

df = (df.assign(CLAIM_STATUS = df['CLAIM_STATUS'].eq(4).mul(df['no_of_claims']))
        .groupby(['Id1','YEAR'], as_index=False).sum())

print (df)
   Id1     YEAR  CLAIM_STATUS  no_of_claims
0    1  2019-01             1             2
1    1  2019-02             1             2
2    1  2019-03             6             8
3    1  2019-04             0             2
4    1  2019-05             0             2
5    1  2019-06             1             2
```

---

```
#used pop for divide and drop columns
df['% of claims rejected'] = df.pop('CLAIM_STATUS').div(df.pop('no_of_claims')).mul(100)
print (df)
   Id1     YEAR  % of claims rejected
0    1  2019-01                  50.0
1    1  2019-02                  50.0
2    1  2019-03                  75.0
3    1  2019-04                   0.0
4    1  2019-05                   0.0
5    1  2019-06                  50.0
```

EDIT:

For better debugging si possible use:

```
df = (df.assign(new = df['CLAIM_STATUS'].eq(4).mul(df['no_of_claims']))
        .groupby(['Id1','YEAR'], as_index=False).sum())

print (df)
   Id1     YEAR  CLAIM_STATUS  no_of_claims  new
0    1  2019-01             9             2    1
1    1  2019-02             9             2    1
2    1  2019-03             9             8    6
3    1  2019-04            11             2    0
4    1  2019-05             5             2    0
5    1  2019-06             9             2    1

df['% of claims rejected'] = df['new'].div(df['no_of_claims']).mul(100)
print (df)
   Id1     YEAR  CLAIM_STATUS  no_of_claims  new  % of claims rejected
0    1  2019-01             9             2    1                  50.0
1    1  2019-02             9             2    1                  50.0
2    1  2019-03             9             8    6                  75.0
3    1  2019-04            11             2    0                   0.0
4    1  2019-05             5             2    0                   0.0
5    1  2019-06             9             2    1                  50.0


df = df.drop(['no_of_claims','CLAIM_STATUS','new'], axis=1)
print (df)
   Id1     YEAR  % of claims rejected
0    1  2019-01                  50.0
1    1  2019-02                  50.0
2    1  2019-03                  75.0
3    1  2019-04                   0.0
4    1  2019-05                   0.0
5    1  2019-06                  50.0
```

Comment: 2 2019-03 4 6
2      2019-03 5 2   I have 2 rows like these and rejected % coming is 12.5 not 75% can you please suggest what is going wrong

Comment: @Python_help - answer was edited, there is multiple `no_of_claims` column for all `claim_STATUS=4` values

Comment: I updated data sample as per your suggestion

Comment: @Python_help - Super, now workign well.

Comment: Why your code is having claim status as 1 and 0

Comment: @Python_help - because assigned `df['CLAIM_STATUS'].eq(4).mul(df['no_of_claims'])` - it means compare to `4` and multiple by column `no_of_claims`.

Comment: @Python_help - added to answer.